# How to share Typescript declarations across Server & Client side projects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, yelp-fusion-api

I've created a server-side library to consume [Yelp Fusion](https://www.yelp.com/fusion) API in TypeScript. the library references a bunch of types/interfaces which I would like to expose to client-side applications, but in a way that is not requiring the **npm install** of the server-side library.

I am thinking to separate the types to their own published package and reference that in both the server and client applications but this seems hard to maintain and I am wondering if there is a built-in or otherwise more efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the types to a different module which you could then reference from both the client and server `package.json`.

You can add it as a local dependency like so:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "myTypes": "file:../path/to/module"
  }
}
```

The only downside is that you need to reinstall the `node_modules` every time you recompile the types.